# WHAT IS DIFFERENCE BETWEEN "STORY" AND "TALE" IN THIS CONTEXT?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

For all their efforts, the diplomats at Versailles achieved the precise opposite of what they had set out to do, inexorably, tragically laying the groundwork for the next, more horrible world war. In this sense, then, the story of diplomacy also reads as a cautionary tale. source: [diplomacy VSI](https://books.google.com/books?id=i0sTiwJQMi0C&pg=PT20&lpg=PT20&dq=thank%20the%20anonymous%20Delegates%20for%20their%20thoughtful%20reports%20and%20constructive%20suggestions&source=bl&ots=0eqkuj4N3J&sig=Bvw7mPdcWirl7cpVnfD24-ZUkbs&hl=fa&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGjOX34PLLAhUDjywKHVAaA-EQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=thank%20the%20anonymous%20Delegates%20for%20their%20thoughtful%20reports%20and%20constructive%20suggestions&f=false)

Comment: It's merely that "story of" is idiomatic, as is "cautionary tale", plus it likely seems to the writer to be a good thing to avoid using the same term twice.

Comment: Hi @yorgun.  I want to invite you, and everyone commenting/answering/voting here, to participate in [this meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7916/13804)

Answer (score 2):

No difference, except that *tale* is a slightly literary or old-fashioned word.

However [a cautionary tale](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cautionary_tale) is a fixed expression, and as with most idioms you cannot replace a word by its synonym in the expression.